# C# get, set accessors in combination with array [system.null reference exception]

Tags: c#, get, set, accessor

I have a problem since I just learned about accessors, I want to learn how to let it work with arrays, this is my script

```
public Vak[] vakken = new Vak [5];
```

the class I use to create the accessors is the next one:

```
public class Vak
{
public string name {get; set;}
public string docent {get; set;}
public int uren {get; set;}
}
```

and in my button click event this is how I want to set it by this command and I don't know why it's givving me the null reference error.

```
vakken[0].name = "Joe";
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you do not instantiate your class. When you create the array of Vaks, make a for loop just after it to instantiate every element like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vakken.Length; i++)
{
     vakken[i] = new Vak(); // this basically allocates memory for your object
}
```

Than you can change the values of every single property of every element in that array.

To clarify, using the *new* keyword you invoke the constructor which is basically method-like block of code which is being executed when you instantiate your class. In your class you did not define a constructor. If you do that the compiler creates a default parameterless constructor which I used in order to create an instance of every single element of your array.

Answer (score 1):

You only initialized the array but no value of the array.

You also have to use:

```
vakken[0] = new Vak();
```

And also for all other elements (you can do this in a loop for example)

Answer (score 0):

You initialized the `array`, but you haven't initialized each *item* in the array. Try:

```
vakken[0] = new Vak();
vakken[0].name = "Joe";
vakken[1] = new Vak();
vakken[1].name = "Dave";
//etc
```